# How do I write the following constraint?

Tags: modeling, constraint, pyomo

I have defined the index for time to be T = [1,2,3,4,5,6]. I want that that the demand that to be addressed twice in a given a time period, when the difference between the time the demand is addressed the first time and the demand is addressed the second time is 2.
Suppose the demand at a location is is given by $D_i$, where $i \in I$ represents the location of the demand and $\omega_{ijt}$ are the number of people who are meant to be located from location $j$ to location $i$ in a time period $t\in T$. Currently I have that $$\sum_{j \in J} \sum_{t \in T} \omega_{ijt} = D_i $$, which will ensure that the demand is allocated to location $j$ in time t. However, how can introduce the idea of having the same demand reintroduced in my model, when the difference between the demand first addressed and the the model time is $2$.

It will help me greatly, if someone could please help me formulate this idea.

Edit: If I have a demand of 40 people at a, 50 people at b, 60 people at c. I want that all of these people at locations $a,b,c \in I$ visit location $j \in J$ within a certain time period $t < T$, where T can be $6$ weeks and $t$ can be 3 weeks . This means that all of the demand can be addressed within 3 weeks. Next, I want that this demand may only visit the facility again if difference between the time that the demand first visited and next visit will be 3 weeks. I do not know how to model this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean

Comment: @Optimization team, in a certain span of say t = 6, I want my demand to be covered. Additionally, I want that if t - t(when demand was addressed) =2, then demand should be readdressed.

Comment: You say in reference to your one equation that it "will ensure that the demand is allocated to location $j$ in time $t$." The right side, however has demand for location $i$, and that demand is not being addressed at a particular time $t$ (since $t$ is an index of summation). Please try to rewrite your question in a clearer manner.

Comment: @prubin, demand is not age dependent..

Comment: Sorry I meant that the demand is not required to be time dependent..

Comment: Yes, but what does "demand is allocated to location $j$ *in time $t$* mean?

Comment: We allocated all of the demand from location i, to location j, within a certain time $t \in T$

Comment: @prubin can you help me with this, since no one else is responding. Please

Comment: Your most recent comment is inconsistent with the equation, which says that demand $D_i$ is allocated cumulatively over the entire time frame, not at a single time $t$.

Comment: Yes, that is right. I want the same demand that is cumulative over a entire time frame(we can say $t<T$) that this demand revists the facility again after the time between the when the demand from location $i$ visited  location $j$ first is say about 2 weeks.

Comment: Is it possible to help me now?

Comment: I think a small numerical example would help clarify the desired behavior.

Comment: For the example you just added, please show both an acceptable solution and an unacceptable solution.

Comment: HI @RobPratt I don't have any acceptable or unacceptable solution. Any solution that satisfies my requirement with modification of my constraint above is acceptable.

Comment: I'm asking for an example of a good schedule (and a bad schedule) to clarify what your requirement means: all 40 people at location $a$ visit location $j$ at time period 2, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128330/discussion-between-jimjamlorde-and-robpratt).

Comment: All of 40 people from location $a$ and subsequently from other locations must finish their visit in 3 weeks time. Next, the same people visit the facility after a break of 3 weeks from their first visit

Comment: Is the assumption that *all* the people from a particular three week period will return *exactly* three weeks after their first visit, or that some unspecified number (but not more than 100% of them will), or that they can return after at least a three week break (but perhaps longer)? Also, can/will they return more than once, or is two visits the limit?

Comment: Yea, I think so, since we have these people in a group. I would imagine that all of these people return together as a group..

Answer (score 1):

When you reason about sums of people moving from $a$ to $b$ and sums of people being at $a$ at time point $t$ you can't reason at a level of the individual. In your formulation you can't express constraints on the position in time of the individual as you currently don't describe the position where an individual is in your model.

To track the position of individuals you need to introduce a boolean array of $\text{is_at}_{p, l, t}$ where $p$ is the unique number of the person and $l$ is it's location at time point $t$.

Since you probably don't want one person to be at multiple locations at the same time you need introduce some constraint like $\forall p \in \text{Persons}, \forall t \in \text{Time}: \sum_{l \in L} \text{is_at}_{p, l, t} \leq 1$ meaning one person can be at most at one location at a time.

On this state it is possible to express that a certain individual needs to revisit the same place 2 time steps later:

$$ (\text{is_at}_{p, l, t} \land \neg \text{is_at}_{p, l, t-2}) \implies (\text{is_at}_{p, l, t+2}) $$

which reads as if Individual $p$ visited $l$ at time point $t$ but not at $t-2$ then $p$ needs to visit $l$ at $t+2$. You might have noticed that this is not in a MILP form but it can be converted into one using  [these equivalences](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12118/136057). Note that around the boundaries of your time interval you can simplify this formulation as $t+2$ or $t-2$ might not exist and you need to define what that means for your model. This formulation will also be a lot bigger then your current one as you are keeping track of individuals and not just sums of people.

You can also modify this formulation to allow individuals to visit after 2 or 3 or 4 days if he never visited this place before:
$$ (\text{is_at}_{p, l, t} \land \neg ( \bigvee\limits_{i=1}^{t-1} \text{is_at}_{p, l, i})) \implies (\text{is_at}_{p, l, t+2} \lor \text{is_at}_{p, l, t+3} \lor \text{is_at}_{p, l, t+4}) $$
Or do another large number of simple modifications that might be able to capture what you want.

Comment: No this is not the correct formulation. I just need a simple constraint a modified version of the one I wrote. Additionally, we can have people at my facilities from different locations.

Comment: According to my understanding of your problem and math there is no such modification. If you want to trace individuals around you can't do so without knowing where persons are. If you want to do something else then please make your question a lot clearer as nobody else seems to get it either.

Comment: my question is really clear honestly. We dont have a unique ID for a person. This may help: If a person from location i visits location j, then he/she must do so after 2 time periods too.

Comment: can you help me write the MILP formulation?

Comment: You can't track individuals without assigning them a separate variables (is_at) and the index into is_at is the ID. Your description is not clear. It might help if you write it in your native language and add that so we can have Google translate your message. @Jimjamlorde

Comment: How do I know about the index is_at when the only people who are to visit the facility at location j, when I do not have a unique ID. Can locations i, be considered as unique ID?

Comment: @Jimjamlorde I just don't understand your english. Can you rephrase? What constraint do you want to impose on the solution?